# How to add unique constraint in kusto table

Tags: kql, kusto-explorer

I am newly working on kusto DB. I want to ignore the data which is already existed in table. So if I use unique constraint then duplicate data won't be get inserted. So how to apply unique constraint in kusto

Answer (score 1):

there's no 'unique' constraint in Kusto.
you can handle duplicate data using a variety of techniques, documented here: [Handle duplicate data in Kusto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/dealing-with-duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

My go-to method is to use the [arg_max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction) function with a `Timestamp`.

It'll grab the latest values for the columns you specify;

```
MyTable
| summarize arg_max( Timestamp, ColYouAreAbout, AnotherColYouCareAbout) by SomeId;
```